# Android update UI of different activity after async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Where I start an async task in activity A, and immediately start activity B. On completion of background task in activity A, I want to update UI of activity B.  Here is the prototype of the code:

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity{
    public void onCreate() {
        // Starting asynctask here
        BackgroundAsyncTask mBackgroundObject=new BacgroundAsyncTask(getActivity.getApplicationContext());
        mBackgroundObject.execute();
        // Start Activity B
    }

    public class BackGroundAsyncTask extends AsyncTask< ... > {
        Context context;

        public BackGroundAsyncTask(Context mCOntext){
            context = mContext;
        }

        doInBackground(){
            // Background Task
        }

        onPostExecute(){
            ActivityB.UpdateUI(context);
        }
    }
}

public class ActivityB extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(){}

    public static void UpdateUI(Context mContext) {
        // **Here I want to update the UI of Activity B , but it is not happening, looks like it is because context is of activity A**
    }
}
```

Any help in implementation of call back listeners or any other implementation would be of really great help. The issue I'm facing is that I don't get any exception but the UI of activity B doesn't get updated.

Comment: It might be preferable to start Activity B in the `onPostExecute()` method instead, and pass whatever new data the Views need as extras on the Intent.

Comment: Where do you call StartActivity() for Activity B?

Comment: @DanielNugent have added the piece

Comment: @MikeM. I cant stop the user waiting for response in background task

Comment: @GeekyCoder Then wouldn't it be easier to create and execute the AsyncTask in Activity B?

Comment: What exactly does Activity A do, and why can't you wait until the AsyncTask is done before you move on to Activity B?

Comment: @Mike can't have this async task /network call executed always on start of activity B :( want the solution to be cleaner

Comment: @Daniel Activity A is login activity , in the async task I would fetch the profile picture of the user , dont want to make user wait till I get the response of profile picture, rather land him on home screen and then update the ui of home screen after I get the image response

Answer (score 0):

create callback from async task

after get result from async task send updated data from activity A to Activity B vai broadcast intent

Register local `BroadcastReceiver` in Activity B

in `onReceive()` method of broadcast listener you can get all upadated data vai intent the update your UI

or

Directly send broadcast from `onPostExecute()` method

Comment: In onreceive you get the context of activity A

Comment: in onreceive it context of activity B

Answer (score 0):

I put a small demo here, it's same as the above.

```
public class TestA extends Activity{
    private final String ACTION_NAME = "bc";    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.run();
                try {
                    sleep(5000);
                    Intent mIntent = new Intent(ACTION_NAME);  
                    mIntent.putExtra("yaner", "发送广播，相当于在这里传送数据");                      
                     //发送广播  
                    sendBroadcast(mIntent);  
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }               
        }.start();      
        startActivity(new Intent(this, TestB.class));
    }
}

public class TestB extends Activity{
    private final String ACTION_NAME = "bc";  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        //注册广播  
        registerBoradcastReceiver();  
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){  
        @Override  
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
            String action = intent.getAction();  
            if(action.equals(ACTION_NAME)){  
                Log.d("aaa", "TestB onReceive:"+intent.getStringExtra("yaner"));
            }  
        }  

    };  

    public void registerBoradcastReceiver(){  
        IntentFilter myIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();  
        myIntentFilter.addAction(ACTION_NAME);  
        //注册广播        
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, myIntentFilter);  
    }  
}
```